# Git Submodule WordPress is getting to big

Tags: git, git-submodules

**Situation**
I use the [WPskeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton) of markjaquith. Which uses the official [WP git](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress) as a submodule.
It works great but it's just so big. The actual files are 20MB, but the `.git` folder is 123MB.
99.9999% is just the submodule of the WordPress submodule.
It's nice to have the whole WP commit history but I could live with just the tags which hold the versions.

**My question is.**
Is there a way to reduce the size of a submodule which I don't own/manage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a `--depth` switch that lets you create a shallow copy of the module. Quote docs:

> This option is valid for add and update commands. Create a shallow
>   clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions.
>   See git-clone.

Didn’t try it, though. Another option would be to use [Git Subtrees](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) instead.

Comment: `git submodule {add, update}`, see [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Comment: Just found it also `git clone`

Comment: I'm struggling to get it. could you give an example? Ideally It would only checkout a tag like `4.1.1`